# TYPO3 realurl optional suffix .html just for certain pages

Tags: typo3, realurl

Is there a way how to adjust the extension realurl (version 1.13.6 or newer) so that an optional suffix ".html" is appended - but just for certain pages.

For example:

**www.mysite.com/page1/
www.mysite.com/page2/**
...

should exist but at the same time

**www.mysite.com/page3.html**

I know that this is possible with a patch of the extension realurl but I want to know if it is possible without any patch!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

There is no setting which makes it possible for that as the configuration is for the complete site and not only for single pages.

I don't know why you need that but you could add general redirects to redirect pages with `.html`to the ones with `/`. I would then also add a canonical tag to avoid problems with search engines.